# Extjs button on the bottom right corner

Tags: extjs, alignment, extjs4.2

this my code :

```
      {
           title: 'XXXXX',
           collapsible:true,
           items:[
                 {
                      xtype: 'button',
                      flex: 1,
                      text: 'click here',
                 },
            ],
       },
```

...

How can I align the button on the bottom-right corner of the container XXXXX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use a `panel` instead of a `container` and place them in the `dockedItems`.

```
....
collapsible:true,
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    items: ['->',{
        text: 'click here'
    }]
}]
...
```

See the docs for more details on [dockedItems](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.AbstractPanel-cfg-dockedItems)

Edit -> without toolbar

```
....
collapsible:true,
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    dock: 'bottom',
    items: [{
        xtype:'container',flex:1
    },{
        text: 'click here',minWidth: 50
    }]
}]
...
```

Comment: Thanks but have you got a solution without toolbar?

Comment: @Meinew You will need some wrapping "container" to nest the buttons into (please see [Buttons](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-buttons) for more information). See my post for a sample edit

Comment: Smart and working : thanks! (Can you link the mentioned post, please?)